# How to use a variable correctly through GET?

Tags: php

How can I correctly pass a variable to the path?
**photos.php?fname=MARERINA**

```
<?php
foreach(glob('.$_GET["fname"]./*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }
?>
```

Comment: 303 posts in the `php` tag and you can't perform basic string concatenation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **don't let user input into a `glob()` unless you want this directory to be possibly anywhere on your server, i.e. you have a security issue**.

Use string concatenation...

```
$_GET["fname"] . '/*.*'
```

...or double quotes with braces.

```
"{$_GET[fname]}/*.*"
```

Comment: can you show me how please?

Comment: @Kaoukkos: The manual tells you how, as does your PHP book.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<?php
foreach(dirname(__file__).glob(".$_GET[fname]/*.*") as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }
?>
```

or:

```
<?php
foreach(dirname(__file__).glob($_GET["fname"].'/*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename;
 }
?>
```

But please keep in mind that requesting a file "../" would reveal the parent directory. So you might check the filename for ".." and remove these or print an error...